# Delete first list element using objectify

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to delete the first element of a list which stores data in GAE.

Here is the code

```jsp
List<Greeting> greetings = ObjectifyService.ofy()
       .load()
       .type(Greeting.class) // We want only Greetings
       .ancestor(theBook)    // Anyone in this book
       .order("-date")       // Most recent first - date is indexed.
      .limit(6)             // Only show 5 of them.
      .list();
    int i = greetings.size();
    if(i>5){
      //delete the first element in the list

    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the list greetings has all the data stored using objectify. I want to delete the first element of the list from the datastore. I can delete all of them with `delete()` function from Objectify but I need to delete only the first element. How to do that

Comment: `ofy().delete().entity(yourlist.get(0))`